# Notepad ++ basic programming EVERYTHING BOLD

Tags: html

Ok, please don't hate me for my idiocy. I'm literally beginning programming html RIGHT NOW. so, first problem.

I am following a simple guide to learn the basic html formats and this is all I have:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>www.fuyah.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id= "Header" class = "shared_elements">
<!--#divs don't really do anything, just for organization and targeting with css-->
    <h1>The Adventure Begins<h1>
    <span> this is my page. </span>
    This is the beginning down my road of web development. It begins with one step...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason when I look online at my page, everything is bold. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't closed your `<h1>` tag and also `<span ">` there's unnecessarily `"` in there

```html
<html>  <head>  <title>www.fuyah.com</title>  </head>

<body>

<div id= "Header" class = "shared_elements">
<!--#divs don't really do anything, just for organization and targeting with css-->
<h1>The Adventure Begins</h1>
    <span > this is my page. </span>
    This is the beginning down my road of web development. It begins with one step...
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry guys, I was too quick to ask a question and didn't full around with the code enough. Thanks for helping and not yelling at me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your file in notepad and verify the contents before uploading the file.
2. If your see the file contents differently, do a "view source" in the the browser to see the contents.